# Unity C# JSON won't serialize a private 2D array?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, serialization, private

I've made a custom class and I need to serialize it into a json file for saving.
I've got it so that it will write to the file, but unless I mark the array as public, it won't serialize the data, and will just save a (mostly) blank file.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public class SettingsData
{
    [SerializeField] int[,] schedule = new int[7,24];    //stores the each hour in a 2D array [day,hour]

    public void Save()
    {
        string jsn = JsonUtility.ToJson(this);
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/settings.json";

        Debug.Log(path);
        File.WriteAllText(path, jsn);
    }
}
```

What it spits out:

```
{}
```

What I want it to spit out:

```
{"schedule":[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]}
```

I've tried other JSON serializers(neuecc/Utf8Json and Newtonsoft.Json), and those didn't work

I tried making it a 1D array instead of 2D, and it didn't work.

I even moved the function outside of the class incase it was '(this)' that was messing it up, it wasn't.

Making it public DOES work, but I want this to be private.

How can I get it to serialize without making it public?

Comment: i'm not used to unity json utils, but usually in such cases, i'd create a separate json file model class with public properties for serialization

Answer (score 1):

1D private array can be serizalized.

```cs
[Serializable]
public class JsonDataTest
{
    [SerializeField]
    private int[,] schedule = new int[7, 24];

    [SerializeField]
    private int a = 3;

    [SerializeField]
    private List<int> b = new List<int>();

    [SerializeField]
    private int[] c = new int[9];

    public void Save()
    {
        string jsn = JsonUtility.ToJson(this);
        Debug.Log($"json string :{jsn}");
    }

}
```

log :

```
json string:{"a":3,"b":[],"c":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
```

You can use the MonoBehaviour,like this:

```cs
public class SerializeTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private int[,] schedule = new int[7, 24];

    [SerializeField]
    private int a = 3;

    [SerializeField]
    private List<int> b = new List<int>();

    [SerializeField]
    private int[] c = new int[9];
}
```

To check which one can be serizalized.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html):

```
Internally, this method uses the Unity serializer; therefore the object you pass in must be supported by the serializer: it must be a MonoBehaviour, ScriptableObject, or plain class/struct with the Serializable attribute applied. The types of fields that you want to be included must be supported by the serializer; unsupported fields will be ignored, as will private fields, static fields, and fields with the NonSerialized attribute applied.
```

This basically means that you can't serialize anything you wouldn't be able to serialize in a monobehavior.

Netonsoft's Json.net supports this, you need to do 2 things:

1. Mark the class as `[JsonObject]`
2. Mark each field you wish to serialize with `[JsonProperty]`